# Volley ui freeze on parsing data

Tags: java, android

I'm using this code for sending data to server , but when i want to parser response data on volley `onResponse` method , my UI freezing .

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
{
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) 
    {
        parseFromJsonObject(response);
    }
}, 
new Response.ErrorListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) 
    {

    }
});

RequestHelper.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req, this);
```

And it's parser method

```
public boolean parseFromJsonObject(JSONObject response)
{
    boolean validResponse = super.isValidResponse(response);
    try
    {
        if(response.has("keywords"))
        {
            JSONObject keywords = response.getJSONObject("keywords");
            Iterator<?> langIterator = keywords.keys();
            ArrayList<LanguagesStorage> languagesStorageArray = new ArrayList<LanguagesStorage>();
            while(langIterator.hasNext())
            {
                String lang = (String) langIterator.next();
                JSONObject langValues = keywords.getJSONObject(lang);

                Iterator<?> valueIterator = langValues.keys();
                while(valueIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    String key = (String) valueIterator.next();
                    String value = (String) langValues.getString(key);

                    LanguagesStorage languagesStorage = new LanguagesStorage();
                    languagesStorage.setKey(key);
                    languagesStorage.setLang(lang);
                    languagesStorage.setValue(value);
                    languagesStorageArray.add(languagesStorage);
                }
            }
            if(languagesStorageArray.size() > 0)
            {
                LanguageAdapter languageAdapter = new LanguageAdapter();
                languageAdapter.insert(languagesStorageArray, true);
            }
        }

        return lastParsingStatus = true;
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        RLog.error("Parsing error in keyword Parser " + e);
        return lastParsingStatus = false;
    }


}
```

What is the issue ? Why my UI thread freezing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volley `onResponce` work inside the UI thread

> I recommend you to do parsing inside a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

In your `parseFromJsonObject` method, try to create a new `Thread` and inside that thread execute your parsing data.